# Execute command line commands from web (not NPAPI)

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, npapi

Chrome stopped support for NPAPI. We are using plug-ins that used NPAPI to run cmd commands from web browser but now its not working on chrome.

I want to know if there are any alternatives to NPAPI for opening windows cmd or communicating with windows file system from client browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is a really bad idea.  A *really* bad idea.  I really hope you mean that it was used to execute very specific applications, and not just arbitrary commands.

Second, FireBreath2 is in the works (firebreath's `refactor` branch) and uses native messaging on chrome to allow things similar to what many plugins did, including this application.  Please don't use it to do bad things.

Comment: yes we used it to create directories and launch some python code placed on user system. For doing above mentioned things fireBreath is the answer right? or should i look for some other framework?

Comment: FireBreath is the only complete framework for this that I know of.  FireBreath2 is not fully released yet; you'd need to be willing to jump in and help to use it.  it's close enough to make that viable, though.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. Yesterday I was doing research on this issue and came accross "protol handlers". They let you add a tag like "mailto://" or "rvlink://" in html and that will launch that application. I was thinking of making custom protocol handler for my application and run it on user click event, from that application i can perform my desired tasks on user machine (ofcourse not the bad ones). What do you think about this approach?

Comment: If it works then it might be viable. you'll have to evaluate whether or not it does what you need it to